# Azure perl support

Tags: azure, perl, azure-web-app-service

I would like to know how I can run perl scripts on Azure web app. Just by running `perl -v` indicates that it has Perl installed already. However, the bin folder was within a GIT folder, which is unusual.

I have attempted installing Strawberry Perl on top of that, but running the above command still shows the old Perl version.

Couldn't find any proper documentation for Perl within Azure. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you run shell script installed by Strawberry Perl? (The script sets some variables which is important) Why would you install other distribution of Perl if you already have one? Probably you should investigate what is pre-installed already and try to use it. If you find that it does not cover your requirements and it is not possible to correct with installation of additional **CPAN** modules -- only then it would make a sense to install other distribution.

Comment: @Polar Bear, Re "*Why would you install other distribution of Perl if you already have one?*", Why wouldn't? Having a Perl build that's under your control avoids so many problem. I cringe whenever I see someone using local::lib instead of just installing Perl locally. In this case, the Perl located *isn't even a native build*! It's built for MSYS, a unix emulation environment. Worse, it's sole purpose is to power `git`, so it could be crippled, and it's gotta make installing modules hard. Not using this build is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: Re "*running the above command still shows the old Perl version.*", It comes down to which one is first in the PATH (unless you use the full path to it). I'm pretty sure Strawberry Perl adds itself to the start of the PATH, but it's possible that you were suppose to run a script as part of the installation process to make that happen like Polar Bear said.

Comment: @ikegami Well if this perl installation is purposed for GIT then probably it is not a good idea to try 'extend' it -- it can break GIT toolset. Well, although I at this moment work in Windows 10 with Perl, but in Linux I find it is much easier to do practically anything (may be except specialized packages which is available only in Windows environment). Docker in my opinion is much better tool for virtualization that Azure (I do not use Azure and I can not do full comparison).

Comment: *Not using this build is definitely the way to go. (Accidentally included an extra "not" in my original comment)